# How to output/display Fatal Errors to browser on HHVM

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, hhvm, homestead

After a day searching for solutions i hope to find an answer here.

I'm running Laravel 4.2 on Homestead 2.0 (Vagrant) and i'm trying to get a simple parse error to output to my browser, but instead i keep getting a white screen.

I can find the error by running 'hhvm index.php' on the Vagrant machine, but that's not what i'm looking for, i would like to output it in my browser.

Are there any options to make this happen?

Tried using hhvm: false in my Homestead.yaml but this seems to be ignored? How is it even possible to run Homestead without hhvm? Would solve my problem to -_-.

Found [hhvm-fastcgi + nginx how to make it display fatal errors in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086903/hhvm-fastcgi-nginx-how-to-make-it-display-fatal-errors-in-the-browser) one but without any answers and from facebook

> These are options you put in /etc/hhvm/config.hdf. We are in the process of killing the .hdf file in favor of a standard php.ini

Tried [Setting an set_error_handler](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) but doesn't seem to be working either

Any other options?

Comment: Possible duplicate with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995847/hhvmhacklang-errors-warnings-output-into-browser question.

Comment: Could also be something to do with https://github.com/laravel/homestead/pull/140 - some developers are not seeing exception reporting by the framework due to an Nginx config issue.

Comment: Shouldn't be it, i get exceptions, and if use a single php file with a syntax error, same thing is happening and won't show up.

Answer (score -2):

Try going into config > app.php and

```
//change this
debug' => false,

// to this
debug' => true,
```

You're running it locally, right? Have you been able to read Laravel errors before?

Good luck!