# How do you handle laravel invisible 500 internal errors when you already change debug to true?

Tags: php, laravel

1. already changed `APP_DEBUG` in `.env` to `true`.
2. when you switch to an address that doesn't exists it would shows the typical laravel error.
3. when you make mistake deliberately like `echo $var_that_not_exists` it would simply give you an blank page with a 500 internal error in browser console.

why? btw I'm using laravel 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Homestead, it uses HHVM by default. Unfortunately, PHP fatal errors in HHVM go to `/var/log/hhvm/error.log` rather than to the browser.

[HHVM+Hacklang: errors/warnings output into browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995847/hhvmhacklang-errors-warnings-output-into-browser)

Answer (score 1):

Theres a difference in errors here.

Going to a 404 page throws an exception which is then handled by your apps error handler, found in app/Exceptions/Handler.php.

Echoing an undefined variable is a fatal PHP error (depending on your config), which assuming your using PHP-FPM is going to display a 500 error from your webserver.